# Get slope and itercept from a matched linear regression model in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a simple model

```
from sklearn import linear_model
x =[6.1101, 5.5277, 8.5186, 7.0032, 5.8598, 8.3829, 7.4764, 8.5781, 6.4862, 5.0546, 5.7107, 14.164, 5.734, 8.4084, 5.6407, 5.3794, 6.3654, 5.1301, 6.4296, 7.0708, 6.1891, 20.27, 5.4901, 6.3261, 5.5649, 18.945, 12.828, 10.957, 13.176, 22.203, 5.2524, 6.5894, 9.2482, 5.8918, 8.2111, 7.9334, 8.0959, 5.6063, 12.836, 6.3534, 5.4069, 6.8825, 11.708, 5.7737, 7.8247, 7.0931, 5.0702, 5.8014, 11.7, 5.5416, 7.5402, 5.3077, 7.4239, 7.6031, 6.3328, 6.3589, 6.2742, 5.6397, 9.3102, 9.4536, 8.8254, 5.1793, 21.279, 14.908, 18.959, 7.2182, 8.2951, 10.236, 5.4994, 20.341, 10.136, 7.3345, 6.0062, 7.2259, 5.0269, 6.5479, 7.5386, 5.0365, 10.274, 5.1077, 5.7292, 5.1884, 6.3557, 9.7687, 6.5159, 8.5172, 9.1802, 6.002, 5.5204, 5.0594, 5.7077, 7.6366, 5.8707, 5.3054, 8.2934, 13.394, 5.4369]
y = [17.592, 9.1302, 13.662, 11.854, 6.8233, 11.886, 4.3483, 12, 6.5987, 3.8166, 3.2522, 15.505, 3.1551, 7.2258, 0.71618, 3.5129, 5.3048, 0.56077, 3.6518, 5.3893, 3.1386, 21.767, 4.263, 5.1875, 3.0825, 22.638, 13.501, 7.0467, 14.692, 24.147, -1.22, 5.9966, 12.134, 1.8495, 6.5426, 4.5623, 4.1164, 3.3928, 10.117, 5.4974, 0.55657, 3.9115, 5.3854, 2.4406, 6.7318, 1.0463, 5.1337, 1.844, 8.0043, 1.0179, 6.7504, 1.8396, 4.2885, 4.9981, 1.4233, -1.4211, 2.4756, 4.6042, 3.9624, 5.4141, 5.1694, -0.74279, 17.929, 12.054, 17.054, 4.8852, 5.7442, 7.7754, 1.0173, 20.992, 6.6799, 4.0259, 1.2784, 3.3411, -2.6807, 0.29678, 3.8845, 5.7014, 6.7526, 2.0576, 0.47953, 0.20421, 0.67861, 7.5435, 5.3436, 4.2415, 6.7981, 0.92695, 0.152, 2.8214, 1.8451, 4.2959, 7.2029, 1.9869, 0.14454, 9.0551, 0.61705]

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit([x], [y])

#where x and y are arrays of values
```

I need to get the slope and intercept. I tried `regr.intercept_` but it returns a large array of numbers that I do not understand what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this to get the correct results:

```py
import numpy as np

regr.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1), np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Without numpy `regr.fit([[x_elem] for x_elem in x], [[y_elem] for y_elem in y])`

Comment: I used `reshape(-1,1)` straight on the arrays of `x` and `y` without numpy and it worked.